# Does x86 have equivalent of Arm FCVTNS (scalar)?

Tags: x86, floating-point, type-conversion, rounding

Arm has `FCVTNS (scalar)` instruction, which is (emphasis added):

> Floating-point Convert to Signed integer, rounding to nearest with *ties to even* (scalar).

A simple question: Does x86 have equivalent of Arm `FCVTNS (scalar)`?

I've already quickly went through the [list of x86 instructions](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/), but couldn't find what I'm looking for. There is a usual [`CVTTSS2SI`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttss2si), which rounds toward zero (when a conversion is inexact), which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtss2si

Comment: Notably, x86 prior to AVX-512 lacks an equivalent of `FCVT*U` to convert floating-point to **unsigned** integer.  AVX-512 added [`VCVTSD2USI`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vcvtsd2usi) and friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-truncating [`cvtss2si`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtss2si) uses the current rounding mode, which is usually nearest-even but can be changed (in the MXCSR, which is what  `fenv.h` affects on x86-64).  Same for packed conversions like `cvtps2dq xmm,xmm`.

The truncating versions exist because C specifies that `(int)my_float` uses truncation.  With legacy x87 (before SSE3 `fisttp`), compilers had to change the x87 rounding mode to truncation and back around every conversion, which sucked a lot.

---

If you need round-to-nearest-even in code that will run with a different rounding mode in MXCSR, you could use AVX-512 `vcvtss2si eax, xmm0, {rn-sae}`  (NASM syntax) to override the rounding mode for that instruction.

Without AVX-512, you could have different rounding modes set in MXCSR and the x87 control word, if you need different rounding in the same loop.  (`movss` store / `fld dword` reload / `fistp` conversion to integer with the current x87 rounding mode is probably more efficient than `ldmxcsr` twice per iteration without a lot of unrolling.  (From two saved values generated with `stmxcsr`.)

(`ldmxcsr` is 4 uops on  Skylake / Alder Lake, but only 1 on Zen.  Its throughput is a bit lower than you'd expect from the uop count and execution ports, though.  See https://uops.info/)